# Removing column duplicate string values and extract the maximum string value for the coulm value

Tags: hadoop, hive

[image]

I want to populate `temp2` with `max tot_duration` and `count from temp1`. I do it using the following code:

```
insert into analytics_db.charith_prepaid_bcell_temp2
(charged_party,cell_id,tot_duration,tband_count)
select  A.*
FROM  analytics_db.charith_prepaid_bcell_temp1  A,
(SELECT A.charged_party,B.B,MAX(A.tot_duration) C-- MAX COUNT FOR MAX TIMA BAND CELL
     FROM  analytics_db.charith_prepaid_bcell_temp1  A,
           (SELECT charged_party,MAX(tband_count) B ---- MAX TIME BAND COUNT
             FROM  analytics_db.charith_prepaid_bcell_temp1 
             WHERE NVL(tot_duration,0) >0
             GROUP BY charged_party) B
     WHERE NVL(tot_duration,0) >0 AND A.charged_party  = B.charged_party  AND A.tband_count = B.B  
     GROUP BY A.charged_party,B.B) C
WHERE A.charged_party = C.charged_party   AND A.tot_duration= C.C AND A.tband_count = C.B
```

[image]

But there are duplicate entries in the `temp2` where there are different cell id with same `tot_duration` and `tband_count` for the same `charged_party`. How can I fix the code to only get the entry where there is only one entry with the maximum `cell_id`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with ranking functions like `row_number`.

```
select charged_party,cell_id,tot_duration,tband_count
from (select t.*
            ,row_number() over(partition by tot_duration,tband_count order by cell_id desc) as rnum
      from tbl t
     ) t
where rnum = 1
```